# Is Thinkpad T14 good for Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

I am planing to install Ubuntu on Thinkpad T14 Gen1 laptop(it comes with windows). I heard previous model Thinkpad T490 works well with linux. Is it same with their new model T14?

Comment: hardware recommendations are off topic on ask ubuntu

Comment: Thinkpads have traditionally been great with Linux although there were some problems with specific recent Lenovo models. I am afraid this is off topic here, but please see http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki which is a site dedicated to thinkpads on Linux. I've owned a t400 and t460, both using Linux, both fine.

Comment: I am sorry. I was not aware of it. Thank you for pointing out @User24601

Comment: Thank you for the information. Thank you for pointing out my mistake @terdon

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will find the answer here.

https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki

Answer (score 0):

So this is the system requirements:
2 GHz dual core processor
4 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
I think your laptop is okay tho there is no problem with new models